# migrating from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on migrating an application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1, most of the things are working but i am getting this error which i am not sure about. The error is

**`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: package_id`**

Here is the complete error log

**

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: package_id
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1764:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1758:in `each'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/base.rb:1758:in `assign_attributes'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:162:in `block in update_attributes'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:194:in `transaction'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:161:in `update_attributes'
    from /Users/tested/Desktop/RailsDevelopement/branch/app/models/package.rb:1131:in `block in void'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:97:in `each'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:97:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/tested/Desktop/RailsDevelopement/branch/app/models/package.rb:1130:in `void'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/tested/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

**

Any help on this will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please post your complete error log.

Comment: hello pavan i have posted my log

Comment: If you have package id in the database then you should be fine but if you have package id as a database column , then i would recommend you try adding attr_accessor :package_id to your package model . Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: i added attr_accessor :package_id but it still gives me same error